# Stopping SQL query date/time format from carrying over to different sheets

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

When testing inserting SQL statement into Excel using VBA, I discovered something unusual.

I have an existing database which has a date + time field as one of the column. Once I programmed the code into VBA to copy database data into Excel, all the data I specified can copy in Excel no problem, including the date + time field as date format by default.

Here is the code for reference. It is in Microsoft Excel Objects -> Sheet1(Sheet1). For reference AddDT in SQL is the date + time field.

```
Sub MainAuto()

On Error GoTo EH

  'Step 1: Create the Connection String with Provider and Data Source options
  Dim sSQLQry As String
  Dim ReturnArray

  Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

  Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String

  sconnect = "driver={SQL Server};server=server;database=database;uid=ID;pwd=ABCDEFG"

  'Step 2: Open the Connection to data source
  Conn.Open sconnect

  'Step 3: Create SQL Command String
  sSQLSting = "SELECT MacID, DayID, DieID, ActualQty, AddDT FROM [Database].[dbo].[tblDataBdy] order by MacID, DayID desc, AddDT desc"

  'Step 4: Get the records by Opening this Query with in the Connected data source
  rs.Open sSQLSting, Conn

  'Step 5: Copy the records into our worksheet
  Sheet1.Range("h6").CopyFromRecordset rs

  'Step 6: Close the Record Set and Connection
  rs.Close
  Conn.Close

  Exit Sub
EH:

 MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Once the macro is activated and data is copied into Excel the AddDT data fills into column L. In order to automate it I inserted a timer function into the code.

```vb
 'Step 6: Close the Record Set and Connection
       rs.Close
       Conn.Close

 Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00.20"), "Sheet1.MainAuto"

       Exit Sub
EH:

 MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Although SQL query is now automated, it now affects other sheets that I'm looking at as well. Say for example I have another sheet in the same workbook (Sheet2) that has a number field in column L. Whenever the timer activates and Sheet2 is open, the number format in Sheet2, column L ends up becoming date format similar to Sheet1, column L. I tested it on other sheets as well, they all change format on the exact same column as Sheet1.

Is there something wrong with the code?

EDIT:

After running the code line by line (Thanks for the suggestion K.Davis), I found that the numbers in Sheet 2 change after VBA passes the code:

```
Sheet1.Range("h6").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

But why? I specified Sheet1 so why did the format of column L spill over to other sheets as well?

EDIT2:

I figured out a temporary solution to the issue, where I move the table containing the SQL search results to a different column far away from original column (from column H to AF). Since none of my other sheets have any data on that column, the issue seems to be averted for now. But that's just avoiding the issue rather than solving it. So I'm still open for suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not seeing anything in your provided coding that would change your number formats. My suggestion would be to run through your code line by line with F8 and see which line causes your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found the line which caused the issue. Updated the question.

Comment: I wonder if you can copy the `rs` into an array, then use the array to post your value(s).

Answer (score 1):

I won't lie to you, I am not overly familiar with SQL. With that being said, you should be able to place your data into an array and use the array to place the values onto your worksheet.

So your step 5, try this:

```vb
'Step 5: Copy the records into our worksheet
Dim rsData As Variant
rsData = rs.GetRows([rows],[start],[fields])
Sheet1.Range("H6") = rsData
```

Another method is that you can use a temporary workbook to copy the data

```vb
'Step 5: Copy the records into our worksheet
Dim wbTemp As Workbook
Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Add
wbTemp.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
Sheet1.Range("H6") = wbTemp.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
wbTemp.Saved = True
wbTemp.Close
Set wbTemp = Nothing
```

Comment: Tried 1st suggestion. Now it shows message "Out of Memory". What is that?

Comment: If your SQL database is large, then you may need to specify the `[rows]` within `GetRows`. It's probably trying to copy the entire database into the array.

Comment: My current database is 461 rows large (and counting every day) and out of 9 fields I'm only using 5 fields only. Is that too big to copy?

Comment: @hjh93 I am not sure how to answer your question. You may want to try my second method if the 1st one doesn't work for you.

Comment: 2nd method gives me an "Object Required" message. It opens a new Excel file and nothing happens.